# One-to-Many Self Reference Association ef code first not working

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

im trying to create a category that is able to contain a parent category and child categories. But for some reason it wont map it right in my db.

This is my class:

```
public class Category:EntityBase
{
    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }

    public List<ProductBase> Products { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

With entitybase being an abstract class with the id as a guid and some other info.

My modelbuilder is as follows:

```
builder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasOptional(i => i.ParentCategory)
                .WithMany(i => i.ChildCategories)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.ParentCategoryId);
```

This is the solution i have found in other SO posts. but it only creates one table in my db, and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: It seems correct. What would you expected?

Comment: some kind of reference to my list of products, also some reference to the child categories

Comment: The reference to child categories is self-contained into Category table (you should see a fk to itself). You should have also a Product category with a field "CategoryId" as Fk to Category table

Comment: okay, i have found the category fk in my product table, but would this not limit it so that one product can only be in one category

Comment: Yes, true. But that's you declared it 'public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; set; } public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }'. You should use a list if you want multiple parents.

Comment: i dont want multiple parents. i want a many to many relationship for the products and categories

Comment: Use Many to Many Mapping then:    `modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                .HasMany<product>(s => s.Products)
                .WithMany(c => c.Categories)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("CategoryRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("ProductRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("CategoriesProducts");
                        });`

Comment: ill give it a try, thanks